Excel add-in (xlam) file file won't open
Edit: Am I remembering incorrectly? I renamed my add-in file to disable it, then I opened a new workbook, inserted a module, saved it as "temp.xlam", added it to the list of add-ins, closed Excel, and then tried to open this new add-in. I got the same result as reported below: the splash, and then hung. Is that what is supposed to happen when I try to open an xlam file, or am I remembering correctly that I should be able to open it?


Working in Excel 2021 in Windows 11
Doing some work in VBA, there was a problem that caused me to shut down my files and look directly at my xlam file. In the past, I have been able to open this file and if I remember correctly, what I got was an Excel window without a worksheet but with access to VBA.
Now, when I attempt to open this file, I get the Excel splash and the work file ~$<filename>.xlam appears in the same folder. The splash has a message at the bottom that changes quickly and ends up with Opening <filename>.xlam. Press ESC to cancel (100%). Then it just hangs. If I press ESC, nothing happens, but if I click on the splash and the press ESC, then the splash goes away, a window opens and immediately disappears, and the work file also goes away. The fact that ESC had no effect until I clicked on the splash tells me that Windows did not have focus on the splash, even though it was on top.
I'm able to open other Excel files and they work, including editing VBA, which properly updates the xlam file. So everything seems to be working okay, except that the I can't open the xlam file directly.
I rebooted, and the problem remains.
What could cause the xlam file to not open, even though everything else in Excel seems to be working okay?

Have you tried opening it on another system? The file may be corrupted in some way. Do you have a backup of it?
